# ComponentDidMount returns undefined after initial mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My component correctly mounts after reading from firebase one time but it fails on the second attempt and says that it cant get the value because "snap" is undefined. Im new to react but I assume something is missing a binding?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./solar.css";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { config } from "../config";

let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
let database = app
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child("values")
  .child("Voltage");

class Solar extends Component {
  state = {
    voltage: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      database.on("value", snap => {
        this.setState({
          voltage: snap.val()
        });
        console.log(snap.val());
      }),
      5000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: why are you using `setInterval()`?

Comment: I want the component to update on a 5 second interval

Comment: Right - I've provided an answer that strips the `setInterval` out. Do you want me to re-insert that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setInterval` function is calling the event handler that you're passing for the `"value"` event.

This happens because the `Database#on` method [returns the callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#on) that you pass to `on` (to make de-registration of the event later during your cleanup phase).

So, when `setInterval` calls your callback, it won't be able to pass in a `snap` parameter seeing the callback is invoked by it (rather that the `database` instance) - that explains why `snap` is `undefined`.

Also - I'm not sure what purpose `setInterval` serves here. It seems you just want the component to update (re-render) when a value change is detected in your database. In that case, the call to `setState()` as you have is sufficient for this.

Consider revising your code as follows:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import "./solar.css";
import firebase from "firebase";
import {
  config
} from "../config";

let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
let database = app
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child("values")
  .child("Voltage");

class Solar extends Component {
  state = {
    voltage: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
  
    // Store reference to the "on value" callback for deregistering
    // the event when the Solar component unmounts
    this.valueChangeCallback = database.on("value", snap => {
      this.setState({
        voltage: snap.val()
      });
      console.log(snap.val());
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  
    // If a valueChangeCallback exists from former mount then deregister
    // this callback from you database instance
    if(this.valueChangeCallback) {
      database.on("value", this.valueChangeCallback);
      this.deregisterCallback = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I've gone back and revised my code. This works well for this application. I do want to update a little slower than the database is updating but with this information, I was able to reintegrate setInterval correctly and I know understand how to correctly set this up.

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help. Sounds like a fun project :-)